How do I understand the reason behind the incorrect result in below LTspice simulation?
Shown below is the LTspice simulation for a full bridge rectifier. The simulation shows 'wrong' result for open load condition (Rload =1 GΩ). Ideally it should be same as other 2 cases.

Why is the simulation going wrong? I guess some convergence issues in solving the diode equation for very low voltage drop/current through it?

Not sure but it could also come from the diode's capacitance or leakage current

It's the diode capacitance. If you look at the model for the MUR460, you will see it given as CJO=126.4p. The time constant, taken together with your last resistor value, is about 125 ms.

You also have another problem with simulation. It's taking time steps that are too long. You will get a smoother value with forced shorter time steps. But that's not the answer to your question. Just an observation from that ratty-looking curve.

Try the same for half-wave and it'll still be the same sort of thing. It's all about parasitics.
